# Should I pay off my 6% student loan using the income that I would normally put into my two IRAs?

Tags: united-states, ira, student-loan

Question says it all.  I would fund 10k to two IRAs, or I can put that toward the student loan for the next couple of years until it's paid off.  Which makes more sense?

Comment: How many years, exactly, will it take to pay off your student loan debt at this rate? 2 years? Do you have any other debt?

Comment: @BenMiller - My only debt is the student loan, and I estimate it will take about two years.  Also, at my age I think that I am behind on my IRAs.

Comment: (I don't have enough rep to comment) First off I'm not sure how you are contributing 10k to two IRAs. The limits are described here: http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-IRA-Contribution-Limits
Specifically: > John, 42, has both a traditional IRA and a Roth IRA and can only contribute a total of $5,500 to either one or both in 2014. Since additional money put into an IRA is taxed at 6% (same source as above) there is little point in putting that additional $4500 in your IRA when you could be getting rid of that loan. If you have a 401(k) with a compa

Comment: If the OP is married, both the OP and his or her spouse can each contribute to an IRA. This is probably what he or she is referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would pay off the student loan as quick as possible.

Here's the reason: A 6% guaranteed return-on-investment is pretty good. And that is essentially what you are getting when you pay off your debt. I understand the feeling of being behind on your retirement savings, but when the debt is gone, you'll also have the monthly expense of loan payments gone, so you'll be able to put away even more toward retirement at that time.

The quicker you can get rid of the debt and start saving up for retirement, the better, so I would challenge you to push yourself a little bit to make it happen sooner. See if you can knock this out in 18 months by either reducing your expenses a little more or increasing your income a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided much information. The following would help,

- What is your income vs. expenses? You should budget 20% towards financial goals
- Do you have an emergency fund? Save $1000-2000 for emergencies
- Do you have any other debts?

  - Avoid too much credit card debt until student loans are paid (avoid too much credit card debt in general).
  - Pay off higher interest debt when possible.
- How old are you, or more to the point, what is your time horizon for retirment?
- Are you married? Do you plan to marry soon? kids? health?
- Is your student loan debt $10,000? or is that the amount you can pay?
- Do you own a house?
- What is your credit like?
- Where do you live?
- Do you own a car, do you live where you need a car?

The general idea is to save consistently over time, and get in the habit of saving (for retirement, and for other priorities/purchases). When you have extra money, paying down debt is a good thing.

Examples,

- Suppose you are < 30 years old, you have plenty of time to both save for retirement and pay off student loans.
- Suppose you are > 50, you have substantial retirement savings, but invested in an MBA program - you probably would want to pay off the student loans more quickly.

Some general recommendations:

- Budget 20% for financial (10% for retirement, 10% for debt (student loans) or savings).
- Save 10% towards retirement - if that seems high, start at 6% and increase yearly.
- Plan to pay off student loans within 4-5 years (depends upon amount and income, of course).
- Avoid too much debt while you are paying your student loans.